# Jpa repository not deleting from db

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

So, I have this entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VISITOR_IMAGE")
public class VisitorImage implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "VISITOR_ID")
    private Long visitorId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "VISITOR_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Visitor visitor;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DATA")
    private byte[] data;

    @Column(name = "CONTENT_TYPE")
    private String contentType;

    @Column(name = "SIZE")
    private Long size;

    //getters and setters

}
```

and here I have jpa repository:

```
@Repository
public interface VisitorImageRepository extends JpaRepository<VisitorImage, Long> {}
```

so when I call delete in service, there is no error or anything, but it's not deleted

```
@Override
    public void deleteByVisitorId(Long visitorId) {
        visitorImageRepository.delete(visitorId);
}
```

I can't figure out why it's not deleted... primary key for the table is "VISITOR_ID"

I would add that save works fine.

Any help?

Comment: Set your log to `logging.level.org.springframework.data.repository=DEBUG` in your application.properties. It might give you more info in the console to what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You have mapped vistor as one to one and cascade option as persist i.e "cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST"
It is preventing you from deleting.
To Delete you need to set cascade option to Cascade.All or Cascade.Remove

Comment: I tried both, on both I getthis exception:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "visitor" violates foreign key constraint "profile_image_visitor_fk" on table "visitor_image"
  Detail: Key (id)=(46) is still referenced from table "visitor_image".

But I don't want to delete visitor from visitor table, just the row in visitor_image table

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVED]
problem was on Visitor entity which had

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "visitor", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private VisitorImage visitorImage;
```

I changed CascadeType to only REMOVE and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the alternate method `deleteById` as below

```
public void deleteUserById(long id) {
        visitorRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

Comment: I have tried that already, deleteByVisitorId(Long visitorId), but same thing

Comment: There might be issues in the dependency then, did you try CrudRepository<Class, Long>

Answer (score -1):

Autowire your repository to the class where you have written this delete method.
like

```
@Autowired 
private VisitorImageRepository visitorRepository;
```

then call the delete method.

```
visitorRepository.delete(visitorId);
```

**focus on cascade type**. Due to cascading it will not be able to delete its parent table entry until child is not deleted.

so try commenting the cascade type.

Comment: I did that, just didn't copy that here.. so that is not the problem

Comment: your Contact entity has an @OneToOne with Cascade on some attribute. 
try commenting cascade type... since cascading makes an entry dependent on other. It will now allow you to delete its parent table entry before its child entries are deleted.